# Why does GitHub limit the number of people that can be assigned to a task in certain situations?

Tags: git, github

I've used GitHub for years as in individual. I maintain a repository specifically for tracking issues for a team of designers/developers. Recently I setup an organization for my team and transferred the repository of our to do items (issues) into the organization.

On personal repositories I'm able to assign an issue to up to ten people.

[image: GitHub assign issue to ten people]

Now that the repository is under the control of the organization, the number of people that can be assigned to an issue is limited to one.

[image: GitHub assign issue to one person]

I've contacted GitHub directly but have not received a message back. I need to assign issues to more than a single person. Is this not possible if a repo is managed by an organization?

Comment: I assume we are talking about GitHub Teams or similar level of service?  However, since this is specifically with a website, you likely will have to wait for the response from GitHub, I suspect there is simply a textbox you have to modify to increase the limit.

Comment: The reason I suspect you will have to wait for a GitHub support response, is that I suspect assigning a task to a user, might be an operation that typically was a metered operation.  *It's entirely possible this is a website bug.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GitHub provides different levels of service depending on the plan.  If you're using an individual paid developer account and a free organization account, then those have different numbers of people that can be assigned to a task.

For example, the [pricing page](https://github.com/pricing) states that multiple assignees can only be created for free accounts if the repositories are public.  If you need to have multiple assignees for private repositories, then you'll need to upgrade to Team.